# Ruby how to assign a model association to multiple model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have looked around at questions and have only found what to do if I want to assign an object to multiple models (polymorphic). Basically, I have two models (Day and Schedule) that I want to connect with an association. The problem is that I want to have several Days be able to have a single Schedule:
(day1.schedule == schedule1, day2.schedule == schedule1)

I was using a polymorphic association (I thought it was what I was trying to do), and it was working, but I discovered that it was assigning Day information to imageable for Schedule every time I assigned the Schedule to a Day:
(schedule1.imageable == day2, schedule1.imageable_id == day2.id, schedule.imageable_type == Day)

It's unnecessary information (that will be incorrect if the Day no longer exists) that I don't want Schedule to save, but if I remove as: :imageable, it breaks and I can't .

I basically need a one-way association, and I haven't been able to figure out how to set one up. I want Days to save Schedules, but Schedules to not save *anything* about Days. Is there an association or am I going to be forced to use the Schedule id instead?

```
class Day < ApplicationRecord**

    has_one :schedule, as: :imageable

    validates :day, presence: true

    def after_initialize( args = {} )
        @day = args[:day]
        @schedule = args[:schedule]
    end
end
```

There's nothing in my Schedule class that has anything to do with Day. It's automatically creating an imageable_id and imageable_type method (although I *did* have to create columns for it in my db)

Comment: Why dont you just add belongs_to :schedule on day instead of creating a polymorphic value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need `Schedule has_many :days` :

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :days
end

class Day < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :schedule
end
```

This way, `Schedule` won't save anything about `days` : the information about the relationship will be saved in the `schedule_id` column of the `days` table.

Here's the corresponding [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).